# Getting incomplete transcript from the youtube transcript api

Tags: python

I was trying to get youtube videos transcript but, I don't know why I am getting incomplete transcript from the youtube transcript api.

I am using youtube-transcript-api 0.4.3

here is my code

```
from youtube_transcript_api import YouTubeTranscriptApi

def Transcript(url):
    id = url.split('watch?v=')
    srt = YouTubeTranscriptApi.get_transcript(id[1])
    print(srt)
    # text_list = []
    # for i in srt:
    #     text_list.append(i['text'])
    # text = ' '.join(text_list)
    # print(text)


Transcript('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQMbvJNRpLE')
```

here is the output screen, it is showing incomplete transcript not sure what to do
[image: output]

here is the actual output-

[{'text': 'Translator: Oriel Yu\nReviewer: Queenie Lee', 'start': 0.0, 'duration': 7.0}, {'text': 'By a show of hands.', 'start': 10.134, 'duration': 1.32}, {'text': 'How many of you believe you\ncould replicate this image of Brad Pitt', 'start': 11.454, 'duration': 3.565}, {'text': 'with just a pencil and piece of paper?', 'start': 15.019, 'duration': 2.516}, {'text': "Well, I'm going to show you\nhow to do this.", 'start': 17.964, 'duration': 2.5}, {'text': 'And in so doing,', 'start': 21.151, 'duration': 1.13}, {'text': "I'm going to give you the skill necessary", 'start': 22.281, 'duration': 2.31}, {'text': 'to become a world-class artist.', 'start': 24.591, 'duration': 2.616}, {'text': "And it shouldn't take\nmore than about 15 seconds.", 'start': 27.207, 'duration': 2.86}, {'text': 'But before I do that,', 'start': 30.459, 'duration': 1.38}, {'text': 'how many of you believe\nyou could replicate this image', 'start': 31.839, 'duration': 2.781}, {'text': 'of a solid gray square?', 'start': 34.62, 'duration': 1.56}, {'text': '(Laughter)', 'start': 36.18, 'duration': 1.062}, {'text': 'Every one of us.', 'start': 37.242, 'duration': 1.27}, {'text': 'And if you can make one gray square,', 'start': 38.512, 'duration': 1.738}, {'text': 'you can make two, three, nine ...', 'start': 40.25, 'duration': 3.02}, {'text': 'Truth of the matter is,', 'start': 43.27, 'duration': 1.353}, {'text': 'if you could made just one gray square,', 'start': 44.623, 'duration': 1.92}, {'text': "it'd be very difficult to argue", 'start': 46.543, 'duration': 2.054}, {'text': "that you couldn't make\nevery gray square necessary", 'start': 48.597, 'duration': 3.542}, {'text': 'to replicate the image in its entirety.', 'start': 52.139, 'duration': 2.36}, {'text': 'And there you have it.', 'start': 55.245, 'duration': 1.3}, {'text': "I've just given you the skills necessary\nto become a world-class artist.", 'start': 56.545, 'duration': 3.913}, {'text': '(Laughter)', 'start': 60.458, 'duration': 1.18}, {'text': "I know what you're thinking.", 'start': 61.638, 'duration': 1.49}, {'text': '"That's not real art,', 'start': 63.128, 'duration': 1.216}, {'text': 'certainly wouldn't make me\na world-class artist."', 'start': 64.344, 'duration': 2.675}, {'text': 'So let me introduce you to Chuck Close.', 'start': 67.552, 'duration': 2.41}, {'text': "He's one of the highest-earning artists\nin the entire world, for decades,", 'start': 69.962, 'duration': 4.31}, {'text': 'he creates his art\nusing this exact technique.', 'start': 74.272, 'duration': 3.095}, {'text': 'You see, what stands between us', 'start': 78.167, 'duration': 2.02}, {'text': 'and achieving even\nour most ambitious dreams', 'start': 80.187, 'duration': 2.91}, {'text': 'has far less to do with possessing\nsome magical skill or talent,', 'start': 83.097, 'duration': 4.0}, {'text': 'and far more to do with\nhow we approach problems', 'start': 87.592, 'duration': 2.88}, {'text': 'and make decisions to solve them.', 'start': 90.472, 'duration': 2.0}, {'text': 'And because of the continuous\nand compounding nature', 'start': 93.193, 'duration': 2.76}, {'text': 'of all those millions of decisions', 'start': 95.953, 'duration': 2.139}, {'text': 'that we face on a regular basis,', 'start': 98.092, 'duration': 2.24}, {'text': 'even a marginal improvement in our process', 'start': 100.332, 'duration': 2.42}, {'text': 'can have a huge impact on our end results.', 'start': 103.364, 'duration': 2.41}, {'text': "And I'll prove this to you", 'start': 105.774, 'duration': 1.55}, {'text': 'by taking a look at\nthe career of Novak Djokovic.', 'start': 107.324, 'duration': 2.615}, {'text': 'Back in 2004,', 'start': 110.336, 'duration': 1.25}, {'text': 'when he first became\na professional tennis player,', 'start': 111.586, 'duration': 2.54}, {'text': 'he was ranked 680th in the world.', 'start': 114.126, 'duration': 2.347}, {'text': "It wasn't until the end of his third year", 'start': 116.794, 'duration': 2.19}, {'text': 'that he jumped up\nto be ranked third in the world.', 'start': 118.984, 'duration': 3.93}, {'text': 'He went from making 250,000 a year\nto 5 million a year,', 'start': 122.914, 'duration': 3.749}, {'text': 'in prize money alone,', 'start': 127.144, 'duration': 1.17}, {'text': 'and of course, he did this\nby winning more matches.', 'start': 128.314, 'duration': 3.28}, {'text': "In 2011, he became the number one\nranked men's tennis player in the world,", 'start': 131.594, 'duration': 4.04}, {'text': 'started earning an average\nof 14 million a year in prize money alone', 'start': 135.634, 'duration': 4.17}, {'text': 'and winning a dominating\n90% of his matches.', 'start': 139.804, 'duration': 3.31}, {'text': "Now, here's what's really interesting", 'start': 143.114, 'duration': 2.28}, {'text': 'about all of these very\nimpressive statistics.', 'start': 145.394, 'duration': 3.05}, {'text': "Novak doesn't control any of them.", 'start': 148.444, 'duration': 2.69}, {'text': 'What he does control\nare all the tiny little decisions', 'start': 151.134, 'duration': 3.33}, {'text': 'that he needs to make\ncorrectly along the way', 'start': 154.464, 'duration': 2.637}, {'text': 'in order to move the probability', 'start': 157.101, 'duration': 2.91}, {'text': 'in favor of him achieving\nthese types of results.', 'start': 160.011, 'duration': 3.24}, {'text': 'And we can quantify and track\nhis progress in this area', 'start': 163.251, 'duration': 3.433}, {'text': 'by taking a look at the percentage\nof points that he wins.', 'start': 166.684, 'duration': 3.23}, {'text': 'Because in tennis', 'start': 169.914, 'duration': 1.21}, {'text': 'the typical point involves\none to maybe three decisions,', 'start': 171.124, 'duration': 3.604}, {'text': 'I like to refer to this\nas his decision success rate.', 'start': 175.116, 'duration': 3.441}, {'text': 'So, back when he was winning\nabout 49% of the matches he was playing,', 'start': 178.557, 'duration': 5.099}, {'text': 'he was winning about 49%\nof the points he played.', 'start': 183.656, 'duration': 3.34}, {'text': 'Then to jump up,\nbecome number three in the world,', 'start': 186.996, 'duration': 2.351}, {'text': 'and actually earn\nfive million dollars a year', 'start': 189.347, 'duration': 2.432}, {'text': 'for swinging a racquet,', 'start': 191.779, 'duration': 1.6}, {'text': 'he had to improve\nhis decision success rate', 'start': 193.379, 'duration': 2.422}, {'text': 'to just 52 percent.', 'start': 195.801, 'duration': 1.764}, {'text': 'Then to become not just number one', 'start': 198.502, 'duration': 1.914}, {'text': 'but maybe one of the greatest players\nto ever play the game,', 'start': 200.416, 'duration': 3.343}, {'text': 'he had to improve\nhis decision success rate', 'start': 203.759, 'duration': 2.34}, {'text': 'to just 55 percent.', 'start': 206.099, 'duration': 2.087}, {'text': 'And I keep using this word "just."', 'start': 208.186, 'duration': 2.068}, {'text': "I don't want to imply this is easy to do,", 'start': 210.254, 'duration': 2.099}, {'text': "clearly, it's not.", 'start': 212.353, 'duration': 1.152}, {'text': "But the type of marginal improvements\nthat I'm talking about", 'start': 213.505, 'duration': 3.24}, {'text': 'are easily achievable\nby every single one of us in this room.', 'start': 216.745, 'duration': 4.06}, {'text': "And I'll show you what I mean.", 'start': 220.805, 'duration': 1.985}, {'text': 'From kindergarten, all the way\nthrough to my high school graduation -', 'start': 223.674, 'duration': 3.903}, {'text': "yes, that's high school\ngraduation for me -", 'start': 227.577, 'duration': 2.4}, {'text': '(Laughter)', 'start': 229.977, 'duration': 1.141}, {'text': 'every one of my report cards\nbasically said the same thing:', 'start': 231.118, 'duration': 3.323}, {'text': 'Steven is a very bright young boy,', 'start': 234.441, 'duration': 2.117}, {'text': 'if only he would just\nsettle down and focus.', 'start': 236.558, 'duration': 2.932}, {'text': "What they didn't realize was I wanted that", 'start': 240.252, 'duration': 2.96}, {'text': 'even more than they wanted it for me,', 'start': 243.212, 'duration': 2.419}, {'text': "I just couldn't.", 'start': 245.631, 'duration': 1.181}, {'text': 'And so, from kindergarten\nstraight through the 2nd year of college,', 'start': 247.371, 'duration': 3.88}, {'text': 'I was a really consistent C, C- student.', 'start': 251.251, 'duration': 4.07}, {'text': 'But then going into my junior year,', 'start': 255.321, 'duration': 1.69}, {'text': "I'd had enough.", 'start': 257.011, 'duration': 1.331}, {'text': 'I thought I want to make a change.', 'start': 258.342, 'duration': 1.619}, {'text': "I'm going to make a marginal adjustment,", 'start': 259.961, 'duration': 2.023}, {'text': "and I'm going to stop being a spectator\nof my decision-making", 'start': 261.984, 'duration': 2.939}, {'text': 'and start becoming an active participant.', '

Comment: Works fine here, without modification. Can you collect the actual output of the script and post it, rather than a screenshot?

Comment: Now I have added the actual output

Comment: I also get full output - what platform are you on and what console are you using. I'm 98% sure this is an issue with your console and not your code.

Comment: yes, you were right my terminal was not showing me the complete output. It was truncating the output. Thanks a lot.